# jQuery DataTables add country icons each column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add in [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) a [country icon](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/) on each `country` column (with jQuery) which is the same as the text that is displayed on that column.

So when it contains the country US then there is a image before the text that will link to `us.png`.

So, from this:

[image: Row without flag icons]

to this:

[image: Row with flag icons]

<sub>(Edited in Chrome DevTools)</sub>

I think it can be done with [`aaData`](http://datatables.net/ref#aaData), but I don't know how to use that without replacing the whole column.

Somebody has an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `fnRowCallback`.

Refer this example from the datatables documentation http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html