# Add checked icon to selected rows in DT shiny

Tags: javascript, css, shiny, dt

I have a DT table in shiny app that have background color set to match certain values. I'm also using the selected rows in table to control other part of the app. Now my problem is to make it obvious which rows are selected.

Usually selected rows in table will have background color changed, but I don't have this option since I set the background color already and don't want to change it. Changing foreground color (font color) for selected rows is not optimal as this is not obvious and intuitive.

Right now I'm making selected rows have different opacity with unselected rows, which works to some degree but still not optimal.

One approach can be add some checked icon to the selected rows. Note I don't want real checkbox input because that will lead user to click the checkbox, while I think it's easier just to click row to select.

There are some examples to show html content in DT table, however that will mean dynamically change table content by row selection, which is not acceptable to my app, since each table content change will trigger table refresh, which reset the row selection and come into a loop.

I think it should be possible to use js to change selected rows css class and thus add a checked icon to them. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675841/datatable-adding-icon-to-select-rows) which is kind of similar, however the example is hard to understand to me.

Update: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56405204/1100107) by @Stéphane Laurent solved my problem exactly. I searched SO extensively before but didn't find this.

Update 2: My use cases is more complex, and I'm having problems adapting this approach. I need 2 control tables, and I'm switching them based on a radio button control. With dynamic rendering of the table, the excluded status get reset in every switch. Previously I used DT row selection which don't have this problem.

See example below, exclude some rows in table 1, switch to table 2, then switch back, the exclude status is restored.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
# DT checked js ----
rowNames <- FALSE # whether to show row names in the table
colIndex <- as.integer(rowNames)
# making variants since we have two table. not worth a function since only two instances. main changes are function name and shiny input id excludedRows
callback1 <- c(
  sprintf("table.on('click', 'td:nth-child(%d)', function(){", colIndex+1),
  "  var td = this;",
  "  var cell = table.cell(td);",
  "  if(cell.data() === 'ok'){",
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  } else {",
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "  }",
  "  var $row = $(td).closest('tr');",
  "  $row.toggleClass('excluded');",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('excluded')){",
  "      excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id').split('_')[1]));",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows1', excludedRows);",
  "})"
)
callback2 <- c(
  sprintf("table.on('click', 'td:nth-child(%d)', function(){", colIndex+1),
  "  var td = this;",
  "  var cell = table.cell(td);",
  "  if(cell.data() === 'ok'){",
  "    cell.data('remove');",
  "  } else {",
  "    cell.data('ok');",
  "  }",
  "  var $row = $(td).closest('tr');",
  "  $row.toggleClass('excluded');",
  "  var excludedRows = [];",
  "  table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){",
  "    if($(this).hasClass('excluded')){",
  "      excludedRows.push(parseInt($(row).attr('id').split('_')[1]));",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows2', excludedRows);",
  "})"
)
# for select all, not using it now
# restore <- c(
#   "function(e, table, node, config) {",
#   "  table.$('tr').removeClass('excluded').each(function(){",
#   sprintf("    var td = $(this).find('td').eq(%d)[0];", colIndex), 
#   "    var cell = table.cell(td);", 
#   "    cell.data('ok');",
#   "  });",
#   "  Shiny.setInputValue('excludedRows', null);",
#   "}"
# )

render <- c(
  'function(data, type, row, meta){',
  '  if(type === "display"){',
  '    var color = data === "ok" ? "#027eac" : "gray";',
  '    return "<span style=\\\"color:" + color +',
  '           "; font-size:18px\\\"><i class=\\\"glyphicon glyphicon-" +', 
  '           data + "\\\"></i></span>";',
  '  } else {',
  '    return data;',
  '  }',
  '}'
)
# test app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      ".excluded { color: gray; font-style: italic; }"
    ))
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Excluded rows Table 1"),
      verbatimTextOutput("excludedRows1"),
      tags$label("Excluded rows Table 2"),
      verbatimTextOutput("excludedRows2")
    ),
    column(
      6, 
      tags$label("Included rows"),
      verbatimTextOutput("includedRows1"),
      verbatimTextOutput("includedRows2")
    )
  ),
  br(),
  radioButtons("select_table", label = "Select table", choices = c("1", "2"), inline = TRUE),
  uiOutput("control_table_ui")
  # tabBox(tabPanel("1", DTOutput("mytable1")),
  #        tabPanel("2", DTOutput("mytable2")))


)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
    output$control_table_ui <- renderUI({
    if (input$select_table == "1") {
      column(12, offset = 0, DTOutput("mytable1"))
    } else {
      column(12, offset = 0, DTOutput("mytable2"))
    }
  })

  dt <- cbind(On = "ok", mtcars[1:6,], id = paste0("row_",1:6))
    row_colors <- rep(c("red", "blue", "green"), 2)
    names(row_colors) <- dt$id
  output[["mytable1"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dt, caption = "table 1",
              rownames = rowNames, extensions = c("Select"), 
              selection = "none", callback = JS(callback1),
              options = list(
                # pageLength = 3,
                sort = FALSE,
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", 
                                   ncol(dt)-1+colIndex)), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dt)-1+colIndex),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(className = "notselectable", targets = colIndex),
                  list(targets = colIndex, render = JS(render)) 
                ),
                dom = "t",
                # buttons = list(list(
                #                  extend = "collection",
                #                  text = 'Select All', 
                #                  action = JS(restore)
                #                )
                # ),
                select = list(style = "single", selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
                # select = list(style = 'os', # set 'os' select style so that ctrl/shift + click in enabled
                #               items = 'row') # items can be cell, row or column
              )
    ) %>% 
      formatStyle("id", target = "row",
                 backgroundColor = styleEqual(dt$id, row_colors))
  }, server = FALSE)
      output[["mytable2"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dt, caption = "table 2",
              rownames = rowNames, extensions = c("Select"), 
              selection = "none", callback = JS(callback2),
              options = list(
                # pageLength = 3,
                rowId = JS(sprintf("function(data){return data[%d];}", 
                                   ncol(dt)-1+colIndex)), 
                columnDefs = list(
                  list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(dt)-1+colIndex),
                  list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all"),
                  list(className = "notselectable", targets = colIndex),
                  list(targets = colIndex, render = JS(render)) 
                ),
                dom = "t",
                # buttons = list(list(
                #                  extend = "collection",
                #                  text = 'Select All', 
                #                  action = JS(restore)
                #                )
                # ),
                select = list(style = "single", selector = "td:not(.notselectable)")
              )
    ) %>% 
      formatStyle("id", target = "row",
                 backgroundColor = styleEqual(dt$id, row_colors))
  }, server = FALSE)
    output$excludedRows1 <- renderPrint({
      input[["excludedRows1"]]
    })
    output$excludedRows2 <- renderPrint({
      input[["excludedRows2"]]
    })
    output$includedRows1 <- renderPrint({
      setdiff(1:nrow(dt), input[["excludedRows1"]])
    })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Update 3: Per @Stéphane Laurent 's suggestion, using conditionalPanel solved the problem. Although it's a little bit slower than renderUI, but it's working.

Comment: something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56405204/1100107) ?

Comment: Yes, it's almost exactly what I want. I searched extensively but didn't find this question. However I kind of knew you will be able to answer this question from my previous questions :)

Comment: What is the difference between that and what you want ?

Comment: I still need to adjust the background color, use different icon etc which are some minor details. The solution is perfect. I just hope my changes will not break it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent can you put your link as an answer so I can accept it? I didn't find any other way to mark the question to be answered.

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56405204/1100107). It is slightly improved on [my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DTcallbacks.html) (at the end of the article).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm having some problem here in my customization. I need to remove the rowname, but turning it off with rowname = FALSE caused some error. I tried to read the js code but not sure how to solve it. Sorry, just realized you have a rowname switch on top. Great!

Comment: Are you using the version which is on my blog ? Just set `rowNames <- FALSE` at the third line, and that should work.

Comment: Yes, just saw that. It's great you considered this already!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm having problem adapting the approach to my use case. Can you have a look if the problem can be solved? If it's not, I may have to give up on this nice solution.

Comment: I think that would work if you use a `conditionalPanel` instead of `renderUI`.

Comment: You are right, it worked in the above example. I'll check if it will work in my full user case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I tried with conditionalPanel in my project and it worked without problem. I found you deleted the answer, can you post it again? The whole problem was solved by your solution, and it'll be very difficult for me to find out this solution with my limited js skills. Your answer helped me a lot in my project, thanks!

Comment: My answer has been deleted by a moderator (he/she converted the answer to a comment).

Comment: OK, I think that's because SO don't like answers that just link to outside page. However it's a little bit awkward if you have to copy and format the blog post here again. Anyway thanks for the solution!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, here is another question which is out of my js skill range. In my app I will want some buttons to select all, clear all. There is js code for "restore" which is enable all, but I don't know how to disable all with js. Can you help on this or point out a direction? Thanks!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I also found in my app that sorting the table will reset the selection status to all being selected. However your example don't have this problem. I'm not sure what caused this.

Comment: @ dracodoc, are you sure you set `server=FALSE` in `renderDT` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent you are right, I missed that parameter because it was located in the end of renderDT call... Do you think it's easy to come up with a function to disable selection for all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @StéphaneLaurent 's answer which is a great js based solution and solved my 95% needs. However I need a button to clear all selection and cannot write that one because of my limited js skills. I also forgot the important `server=FALSE` parameter so met problem of sorting lost selection. Thus I switched back to my original row selection mechanism.

I used to try to modify the table by row selection, but that will trigger reactive event loop. Later I realized I only need to change the view, not the underlying data, and changing view is possible by purely css rules.

Checking [the great example here](http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/#shiny-tab-tabcheckButtons), the `more icons` example can show different icon depend on checkbox selection. By inspecting the css rules, I found both icons are there all the time, just the css rule is different depend on selection status.

Thus I came up with this solution, which used the builtin row selection in DT and some css rules, this way you still have all the feature of row selection control in DT without needs of js code, and everything is implemented by css.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
.selected .table-icon-yes {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #3c763d;
}
.table-icon-yes {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}
.selected .table-icon-no {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}
.table-icon-no {
    opacity: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #999;
}
    "))
  ),
  DTOutput("table")
)

icon_col <- tagList(span(class = "table-icon-yes", icon("ok", lib = "glyphicon")),
                    span(class = "table-icon-no", icon("remove", lib = "glyphicon")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 output$table <- renderDT({
   dt <- data.table(iris)
   dt[, Selected := as.character(icon_col)]
   setcolorder(dt, c(ncol(dt), 1:(ncol(dt) - 1)))
   datatable(dt, escape = FALSE)
 }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```